# html.submit button not sending onsever click event

Tags: html, events, c#-4.0

The html code used is

```
<input runat="server" id="SubmitButton" type="submit"  value="submit" onserverclick="MySubmitHandler" /></p>
```

and the c# code is

```
protected void MySubmitHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        ResultLabel.InnerText="Thanks for clicking :)";
    }
```

and code for label is:

```
<label id="ResultLabel" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: blink; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-variant: normal; color: #FF0000; background-color: #00FF00" runat="server" >[Result will be displayed here]</label>
```

Comment: nothing is happening when i clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

Does C# even work in the Browser? Here is a solution with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<input id="SubmitButton" type="button"  value="submit" value="Click Me!"/>
<label id="ResultLabel" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: blink; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-variant: normal; color: #FF0000; background-color: #00FF00" runat="server" >[Result will be displayed here]</label>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#SubmitButton").click(function(e) {
            $("#ResultLabel").text("Thanks for clicking :)");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks,but i already know this way , i am just trying it to do it with html,and yes c# works with the browser Because the website functioning properly with asp.net controls.